# Installing from a folder of debian files

Tags: command-line, software-installation

I have a folder containing debian files for these packages:

```
  advancecomp akonadi-backend-mysql akonadi-server akonadiconsole akregator
  amor analitza-common ark astrometry.net audiocd-kio avogadro-data baloo
  blinken blogilo bomber bovo build-essential cantor cantor-backend-kalgebra
  cervisia chemical-mime-data consolekit dirmngr docbook docbook-to-man
  docbook-xml docbook-xsl dolphin dpkg-dev dragonplayer edict fakeroot
  festival festival-freebsoft-utils festlex-cmu festlex-poslex
  festvox-kallpc16k filelight fonts-dustin fonts-lmodern freerdp-x11
  freespacenotifier g++ g++-4.8 gawk gnugo gnupg-agent gnupg2 gpgsm granatier
  graphviz gwenview icoutils imagemagick imagemagick-common jovie juk
  kaccessible kaddressbook kajongg kalarm kalgebra kalgebra-common kalzium
  kalzium-data kamera kanagram kanjidic kapman kapptemplate kate kate-data
  katepart katomic kblackbox kblocks kbounce kbreakout kbruch kcachegrind
  kcalc kcharselect kcolorchooser kcron kde-base-artwork kde-baseapps
  kde-baseapps-bin kde-baseapps-data kde-config-cddb kde-config-cron
  kde-config-pimactivity kde-full kde-icons-mono kde-plasma-desktop
  kde-plasma-netbook kde-runtime kde-runtime-data kde-standard
  kde-style-oxygen kde-wallpapers kde-wallpapers-default kde-window-manager
  kde-window-manager-common kde-workspace kde-workspace-bin kde-workspace-data
  kde-workspace-kgreet-plugins kde-zeroconf kdeaccessibility kdeadmin
  kdeartwork kdeartwork-emoticons kdeartwork-style kdeartwork-theme-window
  kdeedu kdeedu-kvtml-data kdegames kdegames-card-data kdegames-data
  kdegames-mahjongg-data kdegraphics kdegraphics-mobipocket
  kdegraphics-strigi-analyzer kdegraphics-thumbnailers kdelibs-bin
  kdelibs5-data kdelibs5-plugins kdemultimedia kdenetwork
  kdenetwork-filesharing kdenetwork-strigi-analyzers kdepasswd kdepim
  kdepim-kresources kdepim-runtime kdepimlibs-kio-plugins kdeplasma-addons
  kdesdk kdesdk-dolphin-plugins kdesdk-kio-plugins kdesdk-misc kdesdk-scripts
  kdesdk-strigi-plugins kdesdk-thumbnailers kdetoys kdeutils kdewallpapers
  kdewebdev kdf kdiamond kdm kdoctools kfilereplace kfind kfourinline kgamma
  kgeography kgeography-data kget kgoldrunner kgpg khangman khelpcenter4 kig
  kigo killbots kimagemapeditor kinfocenter kio-audiocd kiriki kiten kjots
  kjumpingcube kleopatra klettres klettres-data klickety klines klinkstatus
  klipper kmag kmahjongg kmail kmenuedit kmines kmix kmousetool kmouth kmplot
  kmtrace knavalbattle knetwalk knode knotes kolf kollision kolourpaint4
  kommander kompare konq-plugins konqueror konqueror-nsplugins konquest
  konsole konsolekalendar kontact kopete kopete-message-indicator korganizer
  kpartloader kpat krdc kremotecontrol kreversi krfb krosspython kruler
  ksaneplugin kscd kscreensaver kscreensaver-xsavers kshisen ksirk ksnakeduel
  ksnapshot kspaceduel ksquares kstars kstars-data ksudoku ksysguard
  ksysguardd ksystemlog kteatime ktimer ktimetracker ktouch ktouch-data
  ktuberling kturtle ktux kubrick kubuntu-debug-installer kuiviewer kuser
  kwalletmanager kwordquiz kwrite libaccounts-qt1 libaio1 libakonadi-calendar4
  libakonadi-contact4 libakonadi-kabc4 libakonadi-kcal4 libakonadi-kde4
  libakonadi-kmime4 libakonadi-notes4 libakonadi-socialutils4
  libakonadiprotocolinternals1 libalgorithm-diff-perl
  libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libalgorithm-merge-perl libanalitza5abi1
  libanalitzagui5abi1 libanalitzaplot5abi1 libao-common libao4 libapr1
  libaprutil1 libastro1 libattica0.4 libavcodec54 libavformat54 libavogadro1
  libavutil52 libbaloocore4 libbaloofiles4 libbaloopim4 libbaloowidgets4
  libbalooxapian4 libblas3 libboost-program-options1.54.0
  libboost-python1.54.0 libboost-thread1.54.0 libcalendarsupport4 libcdt5
  libcfitsio3 libcgraph6 libck-connector0 libcln6 libcomposereditorng4
  libdiscid0 libdlrestrictions1 libdmtx0a libencode-locale-perl libepub0
  libestools2.1 libeventviews4 libfakeroot libfftw3-double3
  libfile-listing-perl libfont-afm-perl libftdi1 libgadu3 libgfortran3 libgif4
  libgl2ps0 libgle3 libgpgme++2 libgps20 libgrantlee-core0 libgrantlee-gui0
  libgsl0ldbl libgsm1 libgvc6 libgvpr2 libhtml-form-perl libhtml-format-perl
  libhtml-parser-perl libhtml-tagset-perl libhtml-tree-perl
  libhttp-cookies-perl libhttp-daemon-perl libhttp-date-perl
  libhttp-message-perl libhttp-negotiate-perl libilmbase6
  libincidenceeditorsng4 libindi-data libindi0c libindicate-qt1 libindicate5
  libio-html-perl libjpeg-progs libjpeg-turbo-progs libjs-jquery
  libjs-sphinxdoc libjs-underscore libkabc4 libkactivities-bin
  libkactivities-models1 libkactivities6 libkalarmcal2
  libkasten2controllers2abi1 libkasten2core2 libkasten2gui2
  libkasten2okteta1controllers1abi1 libkasten2okteta1core1
  libkasten2okteta1gui1 libkateinterfaces4 libkatepartinterfaces4 libkblog4
  libkcal4 libkcalcore4 libkcalutils4 libkcddb4 libkcmutils4 libkcompactdisc4
  libkdcraw-data libkdcraw23 libkde3support4 libkdeclarative5
  libkdecorations4abi1 libkdecore5 libkdeedu-data libkdegames6 libkdepim4
  libkdepimdbusinterfaces4 libkdesu5 libkdeui5 libkdewebkit5 libkdgantt2-0
  libkdnssd4 libkeduvocdocument4 libkemoticons4 libkephal4abi1 libkexiv2-11
  libkexiv2-data libkfbapi1 libkfile4 libkfilemetadata4 libkgapi2-2
  libkholidays4 libkhtml5 libkidletime4 libkimap4 libkio5 libkipi-data
  libkipi11 libkiten4abi1 libkjsapi4 libkjsembed4 libkldap4 libkleo4
  libkmahjongglib4 libkmanagesieve4 libkmbox4 libkmediaplayer4 libkmime4
  libknewstuff2-4 libknewstuff3-4 libknotifyconfig4 libkntlm4 libkolab0
  libkolabxml1 libkomparediff2-4 libkonq-common libkonq5-templates
  libkonq5abi1 libkonqsidebarplugin4a libkontactinterface4 libkopete4
  libkparts4 libkpgp4 libkpimidentities4 libkpimtextedit4 libkpimutils4
  libkprintutils4 libkpty4 libkresources4 libkrosscore4 libkrossui4
  libksane-data libksane0 libksba8 libkscreen1 libkscreensaver5 libksgrd4
  libksieve4 libksieveui4 libksignalplotter4 libktexteditor4 libktnef4
  libktorrent5 libkubuntu0 libkunitconversion4 libkwineffects1abi4
  libkwinglesutils1 libkwinglutils1abi3 libkworkspace4abi2 libkxmlrpcclient4
  liblapack3 liblightdm-qt-3-0 liblqr-1-0 liblwp-mediatypes-perl
  liblwp-protocol-https-perl libmagickcore5 libmagickcore5-extra
  libmagickwand5 libmailcommon4 libmailimporter4 libmailtransport4
  libmarblewidget18 libmediastreamer-base3 libmessagecomposer4 libmessagecore4
  libmessagelist4 libmessageviewer4 libmicroblog4 libmms0 libmodemmanagerqt1
  libmp3lame0 libmsn0.3 libmusicbrainz3-6 libmusicbrainz5-0 libmysqlclient18
  libnepomuk4 libnepomukcleaner4 libnepomukcore4abi1 libnepomukquery4a
  libnepomukutils4 libnet-http-perl libnetpbm10 libnetworkmanagerqt1
  libnoteshared4 libnova-0.14-0 libntrack-qt4-1 libntrack0 liboath0
  libokteta1core1 libokteta1gui1 libokularcore4 libopenal-data libopenal1
  libopenbabel4 libopenconnect2 libopencore-amrnb0 libopencore-amrwb0
  libopenexr6 libopenjpeg2 libopus0 libortp9 libotr5 libpam-ck-connector
  libpathplan4 libphonon4 libpimactivity4 libpimcommon4
  libplasma-geolocation-interface4 libplasma3 libplasmaclock4abi4
  libplasmagenericshell4 libpolkit-qt-1-1 libpoppler-qt4-4 libprison0
  libprocesscore4abi1 libprocessui4a libptexenc1 libpth20
  libqaccessibilityclient0 libqalculate5 libqalculate5-data libqapt2
  libqapt2-runtime libqca2 libqca2-plugin-ossl libqextserialport1 libqgpgme1
  libqhull6 libqimageblitz4 libqjson0 libqmobipocket1 libqoauth1 libqrencode3
  libqt4-qt3support libqt4-sql-mysql libqtlocation1 libquazip0 libruby1.9.1
  libschroedinger-1.0-0 libsendlater4 libserf-1-1 libshp1 libsignon-qt1
  libsigsegv2 libsolid4 libsoprano4 libsox-fmt-alsa libsox-fmt-base libsox2
  libsp1c2 libspandsp2 libsrtp0 libstdc++-4.8-dev libstreamanalyzer0
  libstreams0 libsvn1 libswscale2 libsyndication4 libtaskmanager4abi5
  libtelepathy-qt4-2 libtemplateparser4 libthreadweaver4 libtidy-0.99-0
  libupnp6 libva1 libvirtodbc0 libwcs4 libweather-ion6 libwlocate0 libwww-perl
  libwww-robotrules-perl libx264-142 libxcb-composite0 libxcb-damage0
  libxcb-keysyms1 libxcb-xtest0 libxerces-c3.1 libxml2-utils libxvidcore4
  libyaml-0-2 libzip2 lightdm-kde-greeter lirc lmodern lokalize lskat luatex
  marble marble-data marble-plugins mysql-client-core-5.5 mysql-common
  mysql-server-core-5.5 nepomuk-core-data nepomuk-core-runtime netpbm
  ntrack-module-libnl-0 odbcinst odbcinst1debian2 okteta okular optipng
  oxygen-cursor-theme oxygen-icon-theme p7zip-full palapeli palapeli-data
  parley parley-data phonon phonon-backend-gstreamer
  phonon-backend-gstreamer-common phonon-backend-gstreamer1.0 picmi
  pinentry-gtk2 pinentry-qt4 pkg-kde-tools plasma-containments-addons
  plasma-dataengines-addons plasma-dataengines-workspace plasma-desktop
  plasma-desktopthemes-artwork plasma-netbook plasma-nm plasma-runners-addons
  plasma-scriptengine-javascript plasma-scriptengine-superkaramba
  plasma-wallpapers-addons plasma-widget-folderview plasma-widget-lancelot
  plasma-widget-message-indicator plasma-widget-networkmanagement
  plasma-widgets-addons plasma-widgets-workspace polkit-kde-1 poxml
  python-avogadro python-beautifulsoup python-dateutil python-enchant
  python-iniparse python-kde4 python-levenshtein python-numpy python-pyfits
  python-qt4-sql python-simplejson python-utidylib python-vobject qapt-batch
  qhull-bin qtdeclarative4-kqtquickcharts-1 rocs ruby ruby1.9.1 scdaemon
  setserial sgml-data shared-desktop-ontologies soprano-daemon sound-icons sox
  sp speech-dispatcher-festival step subversion svgpart sweeper systemsettings
  tex-common texlive-base texlive-binaries texlive-latex-base
  texlive-latex-base-doc texlive-luatex translate-toolkit ttf-dejavu-core
  ttf-sjfonts umbrello update-notifier-kde valgrind virtuoso-minimal
  virtuoso-opensource-6.1-bin virtuoso-opensource-6.1-common vorbis-tools
  xscreensaver-data xscreensaver-data-extra xscreensaver-gl
  xscreensaver-gl-extra xscreensaver-screensaver-bsod
```

Is it possible to install these debian files from he folder using command?

Note: The debian files may not be the latest version. The folder has a lot more .deb files and I don't want to add all of them to apt.

Comment: What are the names of files? Are same as package names?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish exactly? It seems you're just trying to install KDE. Why would you do it in such a twisted way?

Comment: @kraxor: to skip downloading 1.5 GB again.

Comment: @FilipSohajek: I think they are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install from local repository

- you can use **apt-get** with a temporary cache directory:

  ```
  sudo apt-get -o dir::cache::archives="/home/user/newcache" install `cat list0.txt`
  ```

  How :

  1. In the file `list0.txt` there is the list of all the **package name**.
     It's enough the one that you posted in the question.
  2. The package files are in the directory `/home/user/newcache` .
     Use, of course instead the directory in which you keep your files.
- you can use **dpkg**:

  ```
      cat list_package_filename.txt | awk '{print "dpkg -i "$1}' | /bin/sh
  ```

  How:

  1. In the file `list_package_filename.txt` there is the list with the **names of the files** for the packages.

Comment: I seems his needs an internet connection and has nothing to do with my folder of debs.

Comment: with the list of the name of packages you can install for each file with `dpkg -i pakage.deb`

Comment: Seems to be a solution. But I tried to solved my problem using [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138007/copying-files-with-particular-names-to-another-folder). btw, I accept this answer, but I have not tested it.

Answer (score 0):

Type in the command:

$ cd /path

to change the path to the folder where you have those packages.

Then run:

$ sudo dpkg -i *.deb

To install the packages.

Comment: it will install all packages in the folder many of which unwanted. I wanted to install just the packages in the list above.

Comment: Then you copy and paste the above file names in terminal in place of *.deb. Remember to add .deb after each filename.

Comment: that's the problem!

Comment: All you have to do is copy and paste.

Comment: I have to search each name then copy and paste.

Comment: But you already copied and pasted it in your question.

Comment: How if I give you a folder with 10000 debian files and you search each of the terms above and when found copy it then paste it in another folder then search for the next term ... Can you do it in 3 hours?

Comment: updated answer: you should do it setting your _cache_ directory instead of the default one...